# Is there be a way to add and remove columns of a Tree Grid

Tags: plugins, extjs4, treegrid, dynamic-columns

I'm working on the Extjs 4 TreeGrid (Ext.tree.TreePanel) and I'd like to manipulate its columns, add and remove them, I searched for something like that in the forum and on google but I can't find anything. Could someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods [removeChild](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-removeChild) and [appendChild](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-appendChild).

s.th. like this:

```
node.appendChild({
            text:"newNode",
            leaf:true
        });
```

Comment: But that would add a row to the tree, not a column

Comment: :) correct ... 
you can hide/show the columns of a grid. If they should be hidden by default you can define this in your columns definition of the grid.
And with 
someGrid.getView().getGridColumns()[i].show();
someGrid.getView().getGridColumns()[i].hide();
you can hide show them. Maybe it's an option to do it this way.

Comment: Yes for the moment that's what I'm doing, I was just hoping there would be a way to dynamically add/delete the columns rather than just showing/hiding them, like we could do with regular grid with some override or else.